# Micronaut possibility to exclude endpoints from http logger

Tags: log4j2, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I enabled logging http traffic by `<logger name="io.micronaut.http.client" level="TRACE" additivity="false"/>`. But I want exclude health endpoint from logging. Is there some config for it? I found some settings at access logger, but it didn't affect these logs. I use log4j2 with xml config.

Comment: Hi. You don't specify which logger you're using, but I guess it's logback. You should write a filter as described in the URL below. You may want to tag your question with the correct logger in order to get a working example. https://sematext.com/blog/logback-tutorial/

Comment: I use log4j2 with xml config

Comment: Thanks. I updated your question with tag log4j2. BR